# How to get resource values from the POM

Tags: maven-2, resources, filtering

I have a dozen configuration properties files for the ant script. These files are used for a customer customization. For example ant should rename *temp_context.xml* to *customer_name_context.xml* where *customer_name* is a property in the conf. file.

Now I would like to reuse the same files in the Maven project.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-files</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <filter filtersfile="${basedir}/config/config.filter.local" />
          <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/${customer}" overwrite="yes" filtering="true">
      </tasks>
      <execution>
  </execution>
```

When I try to execute this plugin the property *${customer}* isn't set to any values. Is it possible to get resource values in the Maven runtime (without profiles)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly I resolve the issue! The [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html) fix my issue!!